# People Picker, userInfo object missing values

Tags: people-picker

I have a people picker field where I get user data using JavaScript.

```
picker.OnValueChangedClientScript = function (elementId, userInfo) {
  var email = userInfo[0].EntityData.Email;
  ...
```

For some reason, and for some people only (not me!), EntityData contain no values (empty string). How could that be? The selected user has an email adress and when I run the code everything works.

Comment: Had a similar issue, where no image data was available for a specific user. It worked after the user visited the SharePoint site.

Comment: Which permissions are granted to user on site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kiril was right in the comment above, it worked after the user visited the site.